# Where to initialize ListView inside ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a listview( that gets some filenames from a folder) inside a viewPager but i'm having trouble initializing the ListView.
I get NullPointerException when setting the adapter for the ListView.
From what i've read,i need to initialize the ListView inside the viewPager but i've tried a lot of stuff and i still get the NPE.
Where do i have to initialize it to stop getting the NPE ?

So,i get NullPointException at `lv1.setAdapter(adapter);`

```
public void citire() {

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

    File directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/InterSRL");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
 lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is the InstatiateItem part:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {


          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.activity_gestionare1;
                View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                gestionare1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gestionare1);
                lv1=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                citire();
                return view;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.activity_gestionare2;
                View view2 = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view2, 0);
                return view2;
            }
            return resId;}
```

And here is the whole activity,in case you guys need it to figure out my problem..

```
public class Gestionare extends Activity {

public List<String> myList;
public File file;
ViewPager vp;
LinearLayout gestionare1;
ListView lv1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestionare);
    citire();
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    MyPagerAdapter adap = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
    vp.setAdapter(adap);

    vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });



}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<LinearLayout> arry;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        arry = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
        // arry.add(new ListView1Page(context));
        arry.add(new LinearLayout(context));
        // views.add(new ListView2Page(context));
        arry.add(new LinearLayout(context));
        // use this when design done graphically
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View view, int arg1, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) view).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {


          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.activity_gestionare1;
                View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                gestionare1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gestionare1);
                lv1=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                citire();
                return view;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.activity_gestionare2;
                View view2 = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view2, 0);
                return view2;
            }
            return resId;}
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {

        return arg0 == arg1;

    }

    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

public void citire() {

    myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

    File directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/InterSRL");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
 lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`lv1` is null when you try to run `citire()`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestionare);
citire();
```

Have you tried moving the code in `citire()` to the `instantiateItem` method? You probably don't need to reinitialize lv1 if you move your code there.

Also, as a general tip, try to use local variables as much as possible, this will help with a lot of the scoping confusion.

Comment: Yes,i tried and i got this `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Gestionare.MyPagerAdapter, int, int, List<String>) is undefined`

Comment: The problem is `this`. When inside your adapter you need to point it to the activity (the Context): `Gestionare.this`

Comment: Changed that,thanks.But it still gives me NPE after moving it to the instantiateItem method.. damn

Comment: did you get rid of the second `findViewBYId`?

Comment: Yes,the only `lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);` is inside the instantiate method